# TFT LTDC Display - Pixels not being written to correct position

Tags: c++, user-interface, embedded, stm32, display

So I've been in the process of porting LVGL to the STM32H743II utilizing a custom alientek board but keep facing issues related to the placement of pixels. Previously I've been able to scale the region down and get LVGL to display correct but any attempt to scale it up to the full width of the screen (1024x600) causes everything to become scrambled and unreadable.

Initially I assumed this was due to the fact that I had not properly set my HBP, VBP etc values but after finding the correct values for the screen here, https://baijiahao.baidu.com/s?id=1671542181706255070&wfr=spider&for=pc, and updated all of them along with utilizing the same equations for setting the Active Width/Height that were included within some of the demo code I still get a fairly scrammbled display.

A good example of the issue I'm facing can be seen in the following picture,
[Lines are render and generally alternate but you can see the overflow as not all the widths/heights are totally consistent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvZ8b.jpg)

```
  for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i++){
 toggle = i % 2;
  for(int j = 0; j <= ACTIVE_W; j++){
     if(toggle == 0){
         PutPixel(j,i,0x00000000);
      }else{
          PutPixel(j,i,0xFFFFFFFF);
     }
 }}
```

the code above is what I used to generate the lines alternating ever other line.

```
#define LCD_WIDTH       1024
#define LCD_HEIGHT      600

#define HFP     160
#define HSYNC   20
#define HBP     140

#define VFP     120
#define VSYNC   3
#define VBP     20
//=================================================================================================
// Areas computation
//=================================================================================================
#define ACTIVE_W (HSYNC + LCD_WIDTH + HBP - 1)
#define ACTIVE_H (VSYNC + LCD_HEIGHT + VBP - 1)

#define TOTAL_WIDTH  (HSYNC + HBP + LCD_WIDTH + HFP - 1)
#define TOTAL_HEIGHT (VSYNC + VBP + LCD_HEIGHT + VFP - 1)
/* Pixel width in bytes */
#define PIXELWIDHT 4
```

this is the code I utilized to actually define the screen values are per specifications for this particular screen.

```
void PutPixel(uint16_t x, uint16_t y, uint32_t color)
 {
    *((uint32_t *) (Bank5_SDRAM_ADDR + (x * PIXELWIDHT) + (y * (LCD_WIDTH * PIXELWIDHT)))) = color;
 }
```

and this is the function I actually utilize to write the values to SDRAM.

If anyone is able to provide clarification on why exactly this isn't working would be a great help as I've been facing this issue not for a couple weeks and its driving me crazy.

EDIT: In response to the comment below I updated the loop to use LCD_WIDTH which makes it look cleaner but its still overflowing and dithering.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcA2p.jpg)

EDIT 2:
So after a little fiddling I was able to resolve the initial flickering issue and now all my configuration values should be correct. I'm still facing weird overflow errors as user yeputons seems to be correct that certain memory addresses are being overwritten.

Comment: In your initial loops, you run `j` out to `ACTIVE_W` pixels, but the `PutPixel` code is assuming a scanline width of `LCD_WIDTH` pixels. That leads me to think that one or both of those are wrong.

Comment: Good catch, I just updated to use the LCD_WIDTH and it looks cleaner but I'm still seeing the same issue. See my updated post.

Comment: Shouldn't `VFP` be `12`? I'm looking at the following formula from the page you linked: `(VSPW+VBP+LINE+VFP) * (HSPW + HBP + HOZVAL + HFP) = (3 + 20 + 600 + 12) * (20 + 140 + 1024 + 160)`

Comment: Also, I'm very skeptical about that `- 1` you have in your `ACTIVE_W`/`ACTIVE_H`/`TOTAL_WIDTH`/`TOTAL_HEIGHT`. That may be *the zero-based-index index* of the last row/columns, but I doubt it's the actual *number* of rows/columns, which is what you need for indexing.

Comment: Ah, you actually use segments instead of half-intervals, so your `ACTIVE_W` is expected to be the last index. Rarely see this. Next idea: you should actually multiply by `TOTAL_WIDTH+1` (please consider changing the name to something like `LAST_COLUMN+1`), not by `LCD_WIDTH`. Also, you should offset all your coordinates correspondingly. Otherwise, some of your `PutPixel` calls in the loop clearly modify the same memory, which is weird.

Comment: Okay so I did have that value incorrect, must have added a 0 to it by accident without realizing but now my entire screen is flickering.

Comment: Will make the following changes based on your suggestions. If you are aware of a better way of doing this rendering this is not my wheel house and will take your method over my own if it actually works.

Comment: Okay so I have made a fairly decent breakthrough. For some reason my PutPixel function is completely consistent for the first 100 pixels but right around x = 130 everything starts to get seriously scrambled and scaled incorrectly. To the point that x=150 ends up  being around double the length of x=100 with the same weird effect seen in the earlier pictures. Prior to that each pixel render completely expectedly.